# Computing the inverse a^-1 mod n using Euler or Fermats Theorem

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm trying to compute the inverse $a^{-1} \mod n$ with Fermat's Theorem (if applicable) or Euler's Theorem:

$a$ = 6, $n$ = 13

I know that since n is prime, we can use Fermat's Theorem to compute the inverse, using the following formula:

$a^{-1} = a^{p-2} \mod p$

So in our case, $p$ = 13.

So here's what I got, but it's obviously incorrect.

$6^{13-2} \mod 13 =$
$6^{11} \mod 13 =$
$362797056 \mod 13$

Can someone please explain where I went wrong?

Comment: $6^{11} \equiv 11 \pmod{13}$, and $11\times 6 \equiv 1 \pmod{13}$. What's the problem? Of course, it's perfeclty acceptable to say that $362797056$ is also an inverse of $6$ mod $13$, but usually you reduce the result.

Comment: $(6)(2)=12\equiv (-1)\pmod {13}\implies  (6)(11)\equiv (6)(-2)\equiv 1 \pmod  {13}.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The remainder on dividing $362797056$ by $13$ is $11$.  Showing this work in more detail and organizing it a little differently, *and* indicating the details of the reductions $\mathrm{mod} \ 13$...

$$\begin{align}
    6 &\cong 6 \mod 13 \\
    6^2 &\cong 36 \cong_{{}-2\cdot 13} 10 \mod 13 \\
    6^3 &\cong 6 \cdot 6^2 \cong 6 \cdot 10 \cong 60 \cong_{{}-4 \cdot 13} 8 \mod 13 \\
    6^9 &\cong (6^3)^3 \cong (8)^3 \cong 64 \cdot 8 \cong_{64 \rightarrow 64 - 4\cdot 13} 12 \cdot 8 \cong 96 \cong_{{}-7\cdot 13} 5 \mod 13 \\
    6^{11} &\cong 6^9 \cdot 6^2 \cong 5 \cdot 10 \cong 50 \cong_{{}-3\cdot 13} 11 \mod 13
\end{align}$$

Then $a \cdot 11 \cong 6 \cdot 11 \cong 66 \cong_{{}-5\cdot 13} 1 \mod 13$.